# Facet by objects(tags) in an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running into a query problem with ElasticSearch.
We have objects that looks like this:

```
{
  "id":"1234",
  "tags":[
     { "tagName": "T1", "tagValue":"V1"},
     { "tagName": "T2", "tagValue":"V2"},
     { "tagName": "T3", "tagValue":"V3"}
  ]
}

{
  "id":"5678",
  "tags":[
     { "tagName": "T1", "tagValue":"X1"},
     { "tagName": "T2", "tagValue":"X2"}
  ]
}
```

And I would like to get a list of tagValues for tagName=T1, which is "V1" and "X1".
I tried

```
{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term":{
            "tags.tagName": "T1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "TagValues":{
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "tags.tagName": "T1"
        }
      }, 
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags.tagValue",
        "size": 30
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like it's returning all tagValues from all tags "T1", "T2", and "T3".

Can someone please help me with this query? How can I get faceted list for objects that's in an array?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to use the [`nested` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) for your `tags` field. Here is the mapping you should use:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/mytags -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "mytag": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "tagName": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "tagValue": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can reindex your data and run a query like the one below, which will first filter only the document containing a `tagName` whose value is `T1` and then using `aggregations` (don't use facets anymore as they are deprecated), you can again select only those tags whose `tagName` is `T1` and then retrieve the associated `tagValue` fields. This will get you the expected `V1` and `X1` values.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/mytags/mytag/_search -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "tags",
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "tags.tagName": "T1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "values": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "tags.tagName": "T1"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "tags.tagValue"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```